# How to obtain the best possible NonlinearFit

Tags: plotting, fitting

Here is some sample data

```
data = {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 2.25}, {0.5, 1.8}, {0.6, 1.5}, {0.7, 1.3}, {0.8, 1.2}, {0.9, 1.15}, 
{1, 1.13}, {1.1, 1.12}, {1.2, 1.11}, {1.4, 1.09}, {1.6, 1.07}, {1.8, 1.05}, {2, 1.03}};
L0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, 
     Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {{0.28, 2.02}, {0.98, 3.04}}, 
     ImageSize -> 550]
```

My objective is to obtain the best Nonlinear curve fit. So I use

```
nlm = Normal[NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b/(c*x^2), {a, b, c}, x]];
P0 = Plot[nlm, {x, 0.3, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[{L0, P0}]
```

The corresponding output is

[image]

So I was wondering if there is another more elegant method to fit all the range of data. The data joined curve is very smooth, so I suppose it must be a better fitting curve available.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "The best" fit is not well-defined. Are there any limits on the number of variables to be fitted? Any functional limitation? Try `a + b*x + c E^(-d x)` e.g.. Without any more info on your data, this will be an excercise in guesswork.

Comment: @YvesKlett You are more than right! Do you think that I should delete the question?

Comment: Technically the code is quite right. If the fit is, nevertheless, not close enough to the data it may be because (1) the data contain some errors, (2) the function used for the fit is not good enough or (3) there are some limitations for the function parameters that should be accounted for (that is what Yves mentioned above). It is typically up to you to decide, what is the case.

Comment: Not sure if you should delete. Perhaps someone can come up with a nice solution. In any case other users can vote for closure, so I´d let it remain a bit to see how it works out.

Comment: There are specialized software packages to search for these kind of things. See for example http://www.nutonian.com/ (check the 30-day free eval demo)

Comment: Is there a typo in the model? Since a+b/(c*x^2) is essentially the same as a+b/x^2. Do you mean a+b/(c+x^2)?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me what is the difference between `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit`. But `NonlinearModelFit` help says:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And `FindFit` says

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, they both indeed produce the same fit, hence both are doing least squares

```
model = a + b/(c*x^2);
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c}, x];
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
nml2 = FindFit[data, model, {a, b, c}, x]
(*{a -> 0.971477, b -> 0.134007, c -> 0.712413}*)
```

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` calls `FindFit` internally to do the fitting. It then wraps the result in such a way as to make it easy to obtain detailed properties of the fit such as the covariance matrix, rather than only the optimized values of the coefficients. If you don't need the additional information, `FindFit` does the job a bit faster, and also takes the option `NormFunction`, which is not supported by `NonlinearModelFit` as some of the properties are calculated assuming that the fit is done according to the 2-norm.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** (This task will not let me go ...)

```
model3 = ((a + b*x + c*x^2)/(1 - a + b*x + c*x^2));
myFit = Normal[NonlinearModelFit[data, model3, {a, b, c}, x]]
```

$\frac{3.79483 x^2-1.70736 x+0.664564}{3.79483 x^2-1.70736 x+0.335436}$

[image]

Just for fun:

```
model2 = a*x^5 - b*x^4 - c*x^3 + d*x^2 - e*x + f;  
myFit = Normal[NonlinearModelFit[data, model2, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, x]]
```

$-1.1015 x^5+8.04168 x^4-23.1188 x^3+32.7078 x^2-22.8711 x+7.47143$

```
p2 = Plot[myFit, {x, 0, 2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0.28, 2.02}, {0.98, 3.04}}];   
Show[L0, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually a linear fit. Since model2 is linear in the parameters {a,b,...,f}. You get the same solution with: Normal@LinearModelFit[data, {1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5}, x].